# How to override security access in Spring?

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Framework 4.0.0 GA and Spring Security 3.2.0 GA. I have applied security to all methods of all classes in a package using a point cut expression as follows.

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false">
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</global-method-security>
```

All methods of all classes defined in the package `admin.dao` would only be accessed by the user whose authority is `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Is it now possible to override this security constraint in some method(s) of some class in this package?

I need to give an anonymous access to some methods in some class under this package (which is already secured).

In JAAS, this can be achieved by using the `javax.annotation.security.PermitAll` annotation above the method in question which will override any global constraints (constraints applied class level, for example).

I have tried with `@Secured(value = "permitAll")` and `@Secured(value = "isAnonymous()")` above the method in question but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false">
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.your.permit.all.dao.*.*(..))" 
          access="permitAll"/>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</global-method-security>
```

make sure to put the `protect-pointcut`permitAll entry first, in this case order is important.

Comment: +1 the pointcut expressions are evaluated in the order you specify them.

Comment: The point cut expression like `execution(* admin.dao.*.methodName(..))` worked as intended but I have to use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` as a value of the `access` attribute even though `use-expressions` and `auto-config` are set to true in `<http>` such as `<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">`. Likewise, `permitAll` works on interceptors like `<intercept-url pattern="/utility/Login.jsf" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>`. Am I missing something about `permitAll`?